# Why is Goddess Kali depicted as standing on Shiva with her tongue out?

Tags: kali

There is a popular saying that while she was roaming, her feet fell on her husband and her tongue came out in embarassment. However, multiple sources claim that as 'not true'. What is the correct depiction and what is the reason behind such a stance of Godess Kali?

Comment: No scriptures mentions this incident and the embarassment.And this question has been asked earlier.But I am NOT voting to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we see Lord Shiva under the feet of Mother Kali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/why-do-we-see-lord-shiva-under-the-feet-of-mother-kali) , [Why Divine Mother's (Kali) tongue is out of mouth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17990/5212) and [Why Devi Tara is shown standing over Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7282/5212)